# NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: Error trying to scrape data from dynamic website using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Ive been working on the following code in which i try to scrape data from a dynamic website(constantly live changing herokuapp website which displays data taken from a sensor).

While looking for some information i try to use selenium but i doesnt seem to work for me. The following part of the code works well:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://lambda-app-eia.herokuapp.com/")
```

Now the error appears right here

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h4 css-2voflx")
```

I dont really have experience working with these types of libraries so any help would be highly appreciated.

I am using google colab btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the class name `MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h4 css-2voflx` which has multiple spaces in it,however in Selenium **spaces are not allowed in the class name**, you can convert this to **CSS selector** like below:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".MuiTypography-root.MuiTypography-h4.css-2voflx")
```

Always check in the dev tool whether the locator is unique or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped!! Although I still dont understand why CLASS_NAME doesnt work, since I took it directly from the h4 tag when looking at the source code. Also, when creating a list containing the data i´ve taken, i got a None list.